# Why are the ModuleEntry32 text values from WinAPI displaying as Chinese characters?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I have been using the JNA (Java Native Access) library to access the memory of processes. I have been writing some code to enumerate through all modules of a process, and the struct `MODULEENTRY32` is obtained properly - I am getting their handles and base addresses properly. However, the "String" values `szModule` and `szExePath` (which are char arrays) that are returned give me random Chinese characters.

JNA provides helper classes for structs such as `MODULEENTRY32` (they call it `MODULEENTRY32W`) for using functions such as `Module32First` and `Module32Next`, which I've been using. They have sort of their own toString method for `szModule` and `szExePath`, and those return the random Chinese chars as well. I have tried to encode/decode it myself, and would get close to the "right" values (encoding to UTF-16, then decoding to ISO) but it still is a bit off - as in I can't use `equals`/`equalsIgnoreCase` to compare it with another String.

Below is roughly an example of what I am getting when printing out `szModule` and `szExePath` in the format `szModule`:`szExePath` returned from the `Module32First`/`Module32Next` calls:

```
瑮汤⹬汤l: 瑮汤⹬汤l
䕋乒䱅㈳䐮䱌: 䕋乒䱅㈳䐮䱌
䕋乒䱅䅂䕓搮汬: 䕋乒䱅䅂䕓搮汬
档潲敭敟晬搮汬: 档潲敭敟晬搮汬
䕖卒佉⹎汤l: 䕖卒佉⹎汤l
獭捶瑲搮汬: 獭捶瑲搮汬
```

And here is roughly how I am enumerating:

```
// hSnapshot is valid, and I already called "Module32First" - this loops through any other modules

while(this.moduleBaseAddr == null && this.moduleHandle == null) {
    Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W currentModuleEntry32 = new Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W();

    if(this.kernel32.Module32Next(hSnapshot, currentModuleEntry32)) {
        currentModuleEntry32.read();

        String currentModuleName = currentModuleEntry32.szModule();

        System.out.println(currentModuleName + ": " + currentModuleEntry32.szModule());

        if(currentModuleName.equals(MODULE_NAME)) {
            this.moduleBaseAddr = currentModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
            this.moduleHandle = currentModuleEntry32.hModule.getPointer();

            break;
        }
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any insight on solving this issue?

Comment: `System.out.println` which string accept ? ansi, unicode ?

Comment: I have no clue, but I'm pretty sure it's unicode. I can't really find a lot of info from searching.

Comment: I was able to decode the bytes from your strings and figure out the issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing ANSI function mappings and Unicode structure mappings.

Most Windows functions have two versions of the function, one ending in A and one in W, with comments in the documentation.  For example, `CreateProcess` has two versions, `CreateProcessA` and `CreateProcessW`, where [the documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa):

> The processthreadsapi.h header defines CreateProcess as an alias which automatically selects the ANSI or Unicode version of this function based on the definition of the UNICODE preprocessor constant. Mixing usage of the encoding-neutral alias with code that not encoding-neutral can lead to mismatches that result in compilation or runtime errors. For more information, see [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes).

That link states:

> New Windows applications should use Unicode to avoid the inconsistencies of varied code pages and for ease of localization.

Unfortunately in the case of `GetModuleFirst` and `GetModuleNext`, they do not follow the usual SDK convention.  There is no -A version of these functions so the mapping you have created is ANSI (really ASCII).  The byte string returned for `szModule` in the first line of the output in your question is `6e74646c6c2e646c6c3a206e74646c6c2e646c6c` which in ASCII or UTF-8 decodes to `ntdll.dll: ntdll.dll`.  Because you are using the `MODULEENTRY32W` (Unicode) structure mapping, these bytes are interpreted as UTF-16, resulting in the characters you are seeing in your output.

The Unicode mappings are `GetModuleFirstW` and `GetModuleNextW`, and are the functions you should be using.  These [are mapped in JNA's Kernel32 class](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/5ac61611f3c4a74ca3c6ed05c4ffafd7c6070e30/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.java#L3714-L3747).  I highly recommend you use the JNA mappings rather than reinventing the wheel.

Incidentally, JNA's `Kernel32Util` class already handles all of this and offers a `List<Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W> getModules(int processID)` method using the correct mappings, that you may find useful.

Comment: Ahhh. This makes sense. The reason why I was doing my own Kernel32 interface was because the JNA documentation suggested that on their GitHub page when using the library. I also included the mapping/helpers .jar provided by JNA as well (as I initially did not include that in my project). I will follow the advice you have given and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Mapping your own is always a good learning experience, or avoids a whole new import for the user mappings, but the `jna-platform` library is the result of a decade of lessons learned by others!